# grails 5 web-plugin profile throwing missing ServletWebServerFactory bean

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, grails-5

**question first for those in a hurry**:

*Should I define a separate ServletWebServerFactory bean for the plugin? Or do I want it to ignore looking for it since it seems to work just fine with the root app's servlet factory*

**Further details:**

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: 
Unable to start web server; nested exception is 
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start 
ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean.

at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:99)
```

I have a multi-project grails app. Root app loads a plugin with the profile "web-plugin"

```
grails:
    profile: web-plugin
```

I generated the plugin scaffolding using the default grails command line (
grails create-plugin), so most settings are default for grails 5.

When I run the main app, it builds and starts the plugin first. When it hits the plugin's generated Application.main method, it blows up

```
 @PluginSource
 class Application extends GrailsAutoConfiguration {
   static void main(String[] args) { 
      //blows up here saying there is no ServletWebServerFactory bean
      GrailsApp.run(Application, args)
   }
 }
```

Then, the root app- which has the ServletWebServerFactory Bean defined - starts fine. From the running root app I can access and run the plugin endpoints even though it encountered the exception..

How should I address the error? To repeat the question: Should I define a separate ServletWebServerFactory bean for the plugin? Or do I want it to ignore looking for it since it seems to work just fine with the root app's servlet factory?

Answer (score 1):

> To repeat the question: Should I define a separate
> ServletWebServerFactory bean for the plugin?

No.

If your dependencies are configured correctly I don't expect you will have the problem if you run the `main` method in the app (as distinct from the plugin).

Comment: haven't found the dependency issue yet, but this points me in the right direction. thanks.

Comment: "this points me in the right direction" - Awesome.  The answer to the question really is "no".  There is no good reason to do that.  Good luck!